# Copy active object rotation values to selected without rotation?

Tags: modeling

the following script is working but how to use matrices instead?

active object has a rotation not applied (it could be the cursor too).
selected objects can have a rotation applied or not.
without making selected objects rotate, the script below, gives to selected objects the active object rotation values.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

cao = context.active_object
name = cao.name
cao.select_set(False)

for ob in context.selected_objects:
    if ob.name == name:
        continue
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=False)
    to_qt = cao.rotation_euler.to_quaternion()
    to_qt.invert()
    ob.rotation_euler = to_qt.to_euler()     
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=False)
    to_qt.invert()
    ob.rotation_euler = to_qt.to_euler()
```

Comment: Could you please outline more clearly what you are trying to achieve.  The above will depend on how many objects are selected. My guess is the result of one active, two selected?

Comment: copy active object rotation values to selected. I give up with you bye